# Method for predicting a curve

Tags: curve-fitting, exponential-smoothing, constrained-regression

I have data on several curves. the data is of the form:
curve_id  x   y,

and there are many x/y pairs for each curve and x is limited to some known range. overall, the curves look quite similar in shape, although, there is of course some noise in the data, and the location of the curves change from one another. some are a bit stretched upward or leftward and so on.

I want to train a model to predict the curve as a whole. at prediction time, I will have very few x/y pairs for the new curve (their number is fixed and known in advance), and I would like to come up with the formula for the curve based on the few "anchor" points.

So I thought about fitting a polynomial or other combinations exponents of x to the data. However, this is not a standard curve fitting in the sense that every curve should have a different equation and the anchor points should help predict the equation.

Also, since there is a limited number of points (let's say K), I can only fit K different exponents, and I think that the main challenge is to find out, based on the data which exponents to use. then, once the new data arrives I can quickly solve for the coefficients.

So, how do I find which K exponents gives the best fit over all curves I have in the training set?

Note: when I played with the data I found out the adding x and x^(-0.5) got me real close. closer than any standard polynomial I tried, which means I am searching K-tuples of exponents that are not necessary positive integers. they can be negative, fractions, etc.

Is there literature on how to search this "exponent space"?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: unfortunately data is proprietary, and simulating similar data will take some time. I'll try to do that, but was hoping that this is not a new problem and that I can get some references or ideas.

Comment: If you were to find a curve with a sufficient overall shape for your needs, and then shift,  stretch and scale based on the value of two or three "pin" points per data set, the noise of those few points becomes a significant factor in the final results.

Comment: Although the data is proprietary, might you post data for a single curve? That would allow suggestions for possible simple curves that you can try on the remaining data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether this is time series data or not. If it is then you would use a time series model. A plot of the data would be nice. Otherwise for non-time series data, playing around with polynomials (or exponentials) is a bad idea. A much more better approach would be to use (natural) splines. This should be available in most software and is much more flexible. With a spline you would define the number of "knots" (or anchor points if you will).